# How to bind dynamic values in the header and how to hide header for the specific pages?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, wkhtmltopdf, nreco

I am using wkhtmltopdf (0.12.6). I cannot achieve the following two things.

- I want to bind dynamic values in the header based on the content.
- I want to hide headers based on the pages.

When I use the wkhtmltopdf, I can inject only one header html. I don't know how to do multiple page header or how to do change the header value.

Comment: Remember that the site's tagging guidelines explicitly tell you to avoid putting tags in your question title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In wkhtmltopdf page header/footer are rendered as separate HTML documents. This means that they don't have direct access to the 'current page' content; however, special 'tokens' - like current page number, total number of pages, current 'section' - are passed as query parameters and they are accessible with JS inside header/footer HTML templates.

Take a look to this wkhtmltopdf help ("Footers And Headers" section): https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

You can paste similar  block and customize (or even hide) header content depending on the page number (or current 'section' - in wkhtmltopdf this corresponds to the value of 'last'  /  /  tags). Note that you can hide the content, but *height* of the header/footer (allocated space on the page) will be the same on all pages because wkhtmltopdf calculates the necessary margin only once (for the first page with the header) and then use the same value for all next pages.

Comment: Can we get value from html element attributes? For example, The section will be in h1 tag and subsection will be in h2 tag.. can we get value from the html element attributes?

Comment: @JeevaJsb You can't - only variables that are passed as query parameters may be used in the header/footer templates ("page", "frompage", "topage", "section", "subsection" etc).